# Angular 2 bundle

Tags: angular

I am curious how should I deploy my angular 2 app. 
For example when I was deploying angular1 I was including the templates in the javascript bundle and used the $templateCache to map them. 
How can I achieve this in angular2.
Thx.

Comment: Still pretty new, but take a look at angular2 webpack.

Comment: this is still ongoing, a build pipeline for build-time template compilation will be done sometime soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using gulp and [gulp-angular-embed-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-embed-templates) and they work great.

P.S. You don't have to switch to webpack if you are already using SystemJs. I'm using [systemjs-builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) to create a production build. It also works in combination with [gulp-angular-embed-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-embed-templates)

This is a simple gulp task for embedding the templates:

```
gulp.task('embed-templates', () => {
    gulp.src('app/**/**.js')
        .pipe(embedTemplates({sourceType:'js', minimize: {quotes: true, empty: true}}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
```

And this is a task for creating the production build:

```
gulp.task('system-build', ['embed-templates'], () => {
    var builder = new systemBuilder();

    return builder.loadConfig('./system.config.js')
       .then(() => builder.buildStatic('app',  'build.js'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into webpack? These guys made a angular 2 [webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) that also contains some documentation to get you started. Similar tools like Rollup or SystemJS are also good options.

Also if you use dart it's a different process, but pretty straight forward with using pub.